# angle to cardinal direction

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I've got two Points (world map):
**P1:** 44.370093, -44.370093
**P2:** 44.370093, -44.370120

I want to calculate the angle to the cardinal direction. So my idea is to calculate the
angle with the vector. The formula that I use is the following:

$$\cos(\mathrm{\phi})=\frac{\vec u\star \vec v}{\left|\vec u\right|\cdot \left|\vec v\right| }$$

Could someone tell me the next steps that I have to do to get the angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most computer systems have an [`Atan2()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function for this.

```
angle = Atan2( y2-y1, x2-x1 )
```

In your case, `angle = Atan2(0.00003, 0) = -π/2`

If you want to use the cosine then you will constrain the angles only between 0° and 180°. If you use the sine rule $$\sin \phi =\frac{ |\vec{u}\times\vec{v}| }{ |\vec{u}||\vec{v}| }$$ then you restrict the angles between -90° to 90°. Combine them to get the full quadrant, which is what the `Atan2()` does.

PS: $\vec{u} = \vec{P}_2 - \vec{P}_1$ and $\vec{v} = (1,0)$.

### Example

$$P_1 = (40.716366666666666, -73.91161666666666) \\ P_2 = ( 40.716483333333336, -73.91175) $$

$$ \theta = {\rm atan2}( (-73.91175)-(-73.91161\overline{6}), (40.71648\overline{3})-(40.7163\overline{6}) ) = \\ {\rm atan2}(-0.00014,0.00012) = -0.86217\,{\rm rad}  = -49.37°$$ from horizontal.

For cardinal directions

$$ \mbox{cardinal deg} = 90° - {\rm atan2}(\Delta y,\Delta x) \frac{180°}{\pi} \\
\mbox{ if angle}<0\mbox{ then add }360°$$

Comment: Hello. So do I have to use this: \sin \phi =\frac{ |\vec{u}\times\vec{v}| }{ |\vec{u}||\vec{v}|? and why is \vec{v} = (1,0)? How do I know when I get the value to which cardinal direction it belongs?

Comment: Ok $\times$ is the vector cross product, and $\vec{v}=(1,0)$ if you are measuring angle from horizontal.

Comment: Like this: P1 = 40.716366666666666, -73.91161666666666 ; P2 = 40.716483333333336, -73.91175 ; Atan2(40.716483333333336 - 40.716366666666666, -73.91175 - (-) 73.91161666666666) * (1,0) /root(40.716366666666666 ^ 2 + (-)73.91161666666666 ^ 2) * root(40.716483333333336 ^ 2 + (-)73.91175 ^ 2)? or is sth. missing?

Comment: If you do the `Atan2()` formula you do not need to divide by $\sqrt{\ldots}$

Comment: See example above.

Comment: Thx. Is your example (the formula) always for the cardinal direction in north? Do I have to add/subtract 90° for the other cardinal direction?

Comment: The convention is always 0° is East, and positive is counter-clock-wise. So subtract 90° and wrap to 0° to 360°.

Comment: See edit now for conversion to 0=North, 90=East, 180=South and 270=West.

Comment: My last question is why you subtract the angle from the 90 degree

Comment: Because if `atan2()` comes up zero it means east and you want east to be 90°. Also when `atan2()` is -90° it means south and you want 180°. That is why you have `90-atan2()`.