# finding the angle in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Suppose we are given cartesian coordinates $x=r\cos\varphi$ and $y=r\sin\varphi$.

In polar coordinates these become $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $$\varphi=\arctan(\frac{y}{x}).$$ My question is why do we have to find $\varphi$ using arctan? If $x=r\cos\varphi$ and $y=r\sin\varphi$ then doesn't $$\varphi=\arccos(\frac{x}{r})$$ and $$\varphi=\arcsin(\frac{y}{r})?$$
These three numbers are not always the same, so how do we know when we can use $\arccos$ or $\arcsin$ instead of $\arctan$?

Comment: If you only wanted the angle $\varphi$ and didn't need the modulus $r$ then $\arctan$ is much quicker. Also using it avoids any mistakes/rounding you may have made in evaluating $r$.

Comment: "These three numbers are rarely the same". I would say that they are the same in at least 25% of the cases, and more.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/640432/3301

Comment: See [another answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782231/confusion-in-converting-the-polar-form-back-to-the-rectangular-form/1782381#1782381) of mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The truth is that you need a function which is usually found in the programming languages under the name $\text{atan2}(y, x)$ and that operates on the four quadrants, hence takes into account the signs of $x$ and $y$.

I don't know of an equivalent in mathematical notation, except maybe $\angle(x+iy)$ or $\arg(x+iy)$ borrowed from the complex numbers

Comment: A way to do $\text{atan2}$ using mathematics is: $2\arctan\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}{y}$ but its a pain to remember.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe remember the argument as $(1-c)/s$, confirmed by $2s'^2/2s'c'$, if you see what I mean ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why do you always use c and s for sin and cos? It takes me a while to decipher what you wrote!

Comment: @MaxPayne: depends on the context. Here the goal was to be concise.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, all three formulas are correct.

If they give different results, this is due to range issues: arccos always has values in $[0,\pi]$, arcsin in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and arctan in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

This is why the [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function is sometimes used, with a range of $[-\pi,\pi]$ : $\varphi=\text{atan2}(y,x)$.

Comment: So can you use all three to get a correct representation in polar coordinates?

Comment: Its easier just to use one then think about which quadrant it is in based on the sign of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(x,y)=(1,-1)$. Can you tell me the angle with your both definitions? Two different results!

$$\arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=\frac{\pi}4$$
$$\arcsin(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}})=-\frac{\pi}4$$

The problem is that the sign of *both* $x$ and $y$ are needed. With $\arccos(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$ the sign of $y$ is lost. That is the case with sign of $x$ in $\arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$.

With $\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ you consider the sign of both parts. Although again due to different definitions of $\arctan$ the signs will be needed at the end.

Long story short, the best is to check the signs whatever formula you use.

Comment: Even with $\arctan$, we need sign of $x$ and $y$!

Comment: Even $\arctan\frac{y}{x}$ won't work with $x<0$.

Comment: @IanMiller Why?

Comment: @IanMiller Are you referring to the two cases if it is in $[0,2\pi]$ or $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: If $x<0$ then you are in Q2 or Q(-2). Most calculators return $\arctan$ in Q1 and Q(-1).

Comment: You asked Why. I was explaining why you can't **just** use $\arctan\frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: @IanMiller Thats why we need the sign of x and y! We know arctan's range is $(-{\pi\over 2} to {\pi\over 2})$ suppose we put (x,y) = (-1,1), in quad 2. We get from arctan: -pi/4. Now we know that its in q2. so it cant be -pi/4. We use our knowledge of coordinates x,y!

Comment: Ok so my initial comment wasn't detailed enough. Perhaps I should have said "You can't simply use $\arctan\frac{y}{x}$. You need to think about it too."

Answer (score 0):

Let the angle be from positive $x$ axis be $\theta$.

$$\tan \theta=\dfrac{y}{x}$$

$$\arctan(\tan \theta)=\arctan(\dfrac{y}{x}) ...(1)$$

Now $\arctan (\tan \theta)= \theta$ is **not** always true as range of arctan is $(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

- So for $\theta\in (\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, it works nicely. For other values of theta, this formula **won't work**.
- Consider the case of $\theta\in (\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})$. Here, we observe that $\tan(\theta - \pi) = \tan\theta$. So that,
  $$\arctan(\tan(\theta - \pi)) = \arctan(\tan\theta)$$
  The advantage of this wil be that $\theta-\pi\in (\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, so $$\arctan(\tan(\theta - \pi)) = \theta - \pi$$ We put his back in $(1)$ to get :
  $$\theta - \pi=\arctan(\dfrac{y}{x})$$ and we get theta. We repeat this for $\theta\in (\frac{3\pi}{2},{2\pi})$
- As you see, to find the interval of $\theta$, we must know signs of (x,y)
- For $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$, there are other definitions in different intervals.  But **as you asked**, it is completely possible to represent all angles from 0 to 2 pi using any of them, provided we use correct definition of functions in different intervals, which would again require sign of x,y to distinguish the quadrant (interval).
- This process is cumbersome and it is much better to use a function (like atan2(y,x) one pointed out by **Yves Daoust**).